# Is there a curated list of known security vulnerabilities related to escrow?

Tags: security, bug

In [Factories Improve Smart Contract Security](https://diligence.consensys.net/posts/2019/09/factories-improve-smart-contract-security/), Steve Marx says that:

> This bug was hand-picked to show the benefit, but this bug is representative of a large class of bugs around escrow. In my experience auditing smart contracts, this is one of the most common places to find critical vulnerabilities.

Is there a public repository for the "large class of bugs around escrow"?

Comment: You have the "Smart Contract Weakness Classification" registry https://smartcontractsecurity.github.io/SWC-registry/

Comment: @Paul so you actually want an answer from us to this question. Normally you are answering your great questions on your own.

Comment: @NiklasFeurstein Yes, isn't it better for everyone to post my questions & answers publicly? And (assuming "great" is sarcastic) I'm sorry if you find my content quality low, but given the fragility of smart contracts, I want to rule out the slightest of doubt I may have on any topic.

Comment: No this isn't sarcastic at all. I really appreciate your anwers as they saved me a lot of trouble already. I was just confused that you post a question once which you can't answer immediately.

Comment: @NiklasFeurstein Oh, sorry! Thank you, that's great to know

Comment: yes, it's called hire security auditors: https://peppersec.com

Comment: @rstormsf I hired some already, but there's never enough questions about security in Ethereum.